# IIS Binding issue - AWS Autoscaling - HTTP 404

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-elb, autoscaling

I am mostly a Linux guy and now working on setting up autoscaling on Windows servers with IIS. We have configured multiple domains on Single server behind ALB with path-based routing in ALB Listener. On the server, in IIS configuration, I have added HTTP --> HTTPS redirection. This is my server setup and it's working fine.

The issue I am facing is after autoscaling happens, new server spins up but gives me HTTP 404. This is because the new server is using the Private IP of the AMI server in IIS binding. To get this working, I have to change the IIS server binding IP - which is not good considering the autoscaling scenario. I understand that this should be a pretty common issue for autoscaling with IIS server, it will be really helpful if someone can guide me through this issue.

Comment: “I have to change the IIS server binding IP”. Who configured the binding initially? Use an "All unassigned" binding if you want the simplest way.